# Custom IOS UITabbarController with hidden top gray line

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'd like to make a view with a unique color with uitabbar i.e I don't want to separate the view into the UITabbar and the rest, so  I've created a custom UITabbar programmatically with custom color. The UITabbar and the "rest of the view" have the same color but there is a gray line on top of the UITabbar that separates the to parts. How can I hide that?

this is an example image, I want to delete that dark line:
https://picasaweb.google.com/felixdl/20Giugno2012#5756005463317234882

SOLUTION

Thank you! this works perfectly! the line I've added is:

[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.jpg"]];

I've never used the "appearance" tag before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're building for iOS 5, you can set the background as an image which would eliminate the grey line you're talking about.

```
[uiTabBarController setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNames:@"my_background.png"]];
```

This does require you to have an image which matches your programitically created color though.

In iOS4, you can override the drawRect function (which is significantly more complicated, but I'd be happy to answer if you're making a pre iOS 5 app)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
** Objective-C **

```
//Remove shadow image by assigning nil value.
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage: nil];

// or 

// Assing UIImage instance without image reference
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage: [[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

** Swift **

```
//Remove shadow image by assigning nil value.
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = nil

// or 

// Assing UIImage instance without image reference
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Here is apple document for [shadowImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/1623452-shadowimage).

```
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
open var shadowImage: UIImage?
```

> Default is nil. When non-nil, a custom shadow image to show instead of
>   the default shadow image. For a custom shadow to be shown, a custom
>   background image must also be set with -setBackgroundImage: (if the
>   default background image is used, the default shadow image will be
>   used).