# Remove UITabBar horizontal separator in iOS7

Tags: ios7, uitabbar, user-experience

I want to remove the horizontal separator line between a UITabBar and the rest of the screen. I'm asking [the same question as this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11104796/1224741) but updated for iOS7.

Setting the background image of my UITabBar doesn't alleviate the problem, nor does setting the background image of the `[UITabBar appearance]` object.

Is this still possible in iOS7? If so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 tabBar-line, how to remove it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939168/ios-7-tabbar-line-how-to-remove-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is pretty much the same as removing the separator of a navigation bar or a toolbar.

Officially, this is only possible by setting the shadowImage to an empty image. However, a closer look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBar/shadowImage), we see that:

> For a custom shadow image to be shown, a custom background image must
>   also be set using the backgroundImage property. If the default
>   background image is used, then the default shadow image will be used
>   regardless of the value of this property.

By using a custom background image, you would lose the blurred background translucency.

The separator is a UIImageView that is a subview of the tab bar. You can find it in the tab bar's hierarchy and set it to hidden.

Answer (score 5):

You could also hide shadow line using this code:

```
[self.tabBar setValue:@(YES) forKeyPath:@"_hidesShadow"];
```

**Swift**

```
self.tabBar.setValue(true, forKey: "_hidesShadow")
```

Comment: Is this using private API? Would this be grounds for App Store rejection?

Comment: ^ yes it is a private, undocumented API and it's use is against Apples terms.

Answer (score 3):

This solution uses a transparent image, so it is more preferable.

**Swift**

```swift
tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

**Objective-C**

```objectivec
tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage.new;
```

Comment: And of course in Swift, that's: `tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage();`